# Does anyone know any seforim about tefillin?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tefilin

I'm very interested in Tefillin and I was wondering if anyone knew of any traditional sources which are either dedicated to or devote serious attention to the meaning of the mitzvah & it's status as a spiritual practice. Not just a hilchot tefillin book, I've got that. I've also read [Aryeh Kaplan's book](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781879016064.html), which is pretty good but the style of which leaves something to be desired. Anyone know of a sefer or two of this kind?

Comment: some of these might help http://zbermanbooks.com/seforim-books/halachah/tefillin-mezuzos

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend this sefer on teffilin alot of interesting information with deep concepts of teffilin. [The Inside story of teffilin](http://www.menuchapublishers.com/tefillin-the-inside-story.html) by Rabbi Moshe Shlomo Emanuel.

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered that I read and liked this short book which perfectly meets your description (available on Kindle for 1$ or in paperback)

[The Splendor of Tefillin: Insights into the Mitzvah of Tefillin from the Writings of Rabbi Abraham Isaac HaKohen Kook](http://amzn.com/B0052UDA82)

From one of the amazon reviews

> Like Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's NCSY booklet on Tefillin, written more than
>   three decades ago, this little gem, "hot off the press," communicates
>   in simple language sophisticated spiritual concepts related to the
>   mitzvah of Tefillin. Many boys prepare for the milestone event of
>   their bar mitzvah by studying the basic laws of Tefillin (whether more
>   or less), but often the profound meaning of what they are doing is
>   barely touched upon. Rabbi Morrison's book, which presents Rav Kook's
>   insights in easily understood modern language, remedies this problem.
>   No doubt many older readers would find it equally enlightening.